# How to configure generate.py pretty to not break apart comments

Tags: qooxdoo

How do I configure the generate.py pretty to stop breaking apart comments like this:

```
// this is a comment
// var a = 10;
```

after running the generator this becomes:

```
// this is a comment

// var a = 10;
```

I can't seem to track down how to stop this in the documentation. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this behavior is not customizable through the config. You either use block comments for those cases, or hack the Python code (I can give you pointers if you want).

In any case you may want to open an [enhancement bug](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/) for this.